# Workflow for SharePoint list updating new column with email address from active directory

Tags: email, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint list with a Name column using the people picker from Active Directory. I've added a new column to show the user email to the existing records. I'm trying to understand the workflow in this response https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/278295/get-email-from-user-and-enter-into-sharepoint-list-field

Is there a workflow to pull in the email address into the new column based on a match to my Name column? I would like to export the records with the email address without manually updating each email and JSON won't show results when exporting the list.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the linked Response, the best way is to use SharePoint Designer WorkFlow 2013, or use Power Automate Flow (newer version), which both can extract Email Value from Person/Group Column.

**Solution 1: Power Automate Flow**

Its already answered in the mentioned Question, with screens

> this solution request Power Automate Flow (flow.microsoft.com) (can be
> even Power Automate Flow Trial)

**Solution 2: SharePoint Designer Workflow 2013**

> - This solution required SharePoint Designer 2013 to be installed.

Create Site WorkFlow, that will loop through every item in the list and set new "Email" column by person/group "Name" column... In `Udapte item in this list` action you can specify, if you want to use DisplayName/ **Email Address**/ Login Name/ User ID

[Picture: Update Item with Email Adress in SPD2013](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7uON.png)

**Solution 3:JSON Column formating** - Set with Buton  (single item)

Not ideal for bulk edit, but someone might find this interesting...

> Recently added feature allows set item properties directly from View by button click. using  `customRowAction` in JSON column formating.

1. Create one single line of text column.
2. Use below JSON code to format the column

```
{  
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",  
  "elmType": "button",  
   "customRowAction": {
              "action": "setValue",
              "actionInput": {
                "TARGETFIELD_HERE": "[$SOURCEFIELD_HERE.email]"
              }
 }
,  
  "attributes": {  
    "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDark--hover",  
    "title": "Set Value"  
  },  
  "style": {  
    "border": "none",  
    "background-color": "transparent",  
    "cursor": "pointer"  
  },  
  "children": [  
    {  
      "elmType": "span",  
      "attributes": {  
        "iconName": "SchoolDataSyncLogo",  
        "class": "ms-font-xxl"  
      }  
    }  
  ]  
}
```